# Listen to Websockets in Angular 4 app with Socket.io

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an Angular 4.x app (client) and on the backend I am using a NestJS app (framework built on top of express) running on localhost:4001 - I can see that the websocket has connected as I can see this in Chrome DevTools within the Network > WebSockets tab with the following response.

```
42["update", {
"accountMessage": {
    "id": 478,
    "text": ""
},
"networksRequireResetting": [7, 8, 4, 9, 21, 49, 100000271, 100000311],
"_id": "5c7401ea28f6c221eca11ff3",
"accountId": 15,
"__v": 0
}]
```

I have a Socket service & another Socket Notification Service - socket.service.ts and socket-notification.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { UserService } from "../user.service";
import { SocketNotificationService } from "./socket-notification.service";

@Injectable()
export class SocketsService {
public socketPort: number = 4001;
public serverPort: number = 3001;
private socket;
public url: string = 'http://localhost';

 constructor(
   private userService: UserService,
   private socketNotificationService: SocketNotificationService,
 ) {}

 public initSocket(): void {
   this.socket = io(this.url + ":" + this.socketPort, {
     transports: ['websocket'],
     query: {
       token: this.userService.getAuth().__token,
     },
     secure: true
 });

   this.socketNotificationService.init(this.socket); // 
}

public send(msg: any) {
  this.socket.emit('message', { message: msg } );
}

public onMessage() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.socket.on('message', msg => {
      observer.next(msg);
    });
 });
}
```

// Socket notification
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
 @Injectable()
 export class SocketNotificationService {
 public socketConnection: any = {};
 public events: any = [];
 public notification: any = [];

 constructor() {

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {

 }

 public init(connection: object) {
   console.log(connection);
   this.socketConnection = connection;
 }

 public listenForEvent(eventName: string, successCallback: any) {

 }

 public disconnect() {
   if (this.socketConnection) {
     try {
      this.socketConnection.disconnect();
     } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Within my component I have the following functions - how do get the `initIoConnection()` to recognise the json data from the websocket response above so I can do some additional logic within the html template?

// within my component

```
    ngOnInit() {
       this.initIoConnection();
    }

    public initIoConnection() {
       this.socketService.initSocket();

       // subscribe
       this.ioConnection = this.socketService.onMessage().subscribe(msg => {
         console.log('got a socket message'); // i never see this log??
       });
    }
```

I console.log out the socket instance and do the .send('some thing here') which performs the socket emit but the onMessage handler never seems to see this - any ideas why this is?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `onMessage()` **before** you call `initSocket()` ?

Comment: thanks for the comment - the initSocket does the connection so has to come before otherwise I no longer see the response in Network > WS tab